# How to delete dependencies when parent attributes change in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, dependencies

I would like to know if there is a way, perhaps in the model class, to delete the dependencies of a parent object if one of their attributes changes that would make it so they no longer have those child objects. Currently, I am deleting the dependencies manually and am looking for a cleaner solution.

For example: Let's say I have a parent class called teachers which has an attribute called teachesGym. All of the teachers that have this attribute set to true will have a child object called gymStudents. If at some point, the attribute changes to false, the teachers should lose the gymStudents child object (I would like said object to be destroyed as soon as the attribute is changed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [after_save](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/after_save). Verify the attributes value and destroy its children. If you don't change its value much, you could also destroy them whenever you change the attributes value.

Comment: Nice and tidy. I'm going to go with this method. Thanks!